# addressing `data` in `geom_line` of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building a barplot with a line connecting two bars in order to show that asterisk refers to the difference between them:

[image: sample plot]

Most of the plot is built correctly with the following code:

```
mytbl <- data.frame(
  "var"  =c("test", "control"), 
  "mean1" =c(0.019, 0.022), 
  "sderr"= c(0.001, 0.002)
);
mytbl$var <- relevel(mytbl$var, "test"); # without this will be sorted alphabetically (i.e. 'control', then 'test')

p <- 
  ggplot(mytbl, aes(x=var, y=mean1)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean1-sderr, ymax=mean1+sderr), width=.2)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent, expand=c(0,0), limits=c(NA, 1.3*max(mytbl$mean1+mytbl$sderr))) +
  geom_text(mapping=aes(x=1.5, y= max(mean1+sderr)+0.005), label='*', size=10)

p
```

The only thing missing is the line itself. In my very old code, it was supposedly working with the following:

```
p + 
  geom_line(
    mapping=aes(x=c(1,1,2,2),
                y=c(mean1[1]+sderr[1]+0.001,
                    max(mean1+sderr) +0.004,
                    max(mean1+sderr) +0.004,
                    mean1[2]+sderr[2]+0.001)
    )
  )
```

But when I run this code now, I get an error: `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2): x, y`. By trying different things, I came to an awkward workaround: I add `data=rbind(mytbl,mytbl),` before `mapping` but I don't understand what really happens here.

P.S. additional little question (I know, I should ask in a separate SO post, sorry for that) - why in `scale_y_continuous(..., limits())` I can't address data by columns and have to call `mytbl$` explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put all that in a separate data frame:

```
line_data <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2),
                        y=with(mytbl,c(mean1[1]+sderr[1]+0.001,
                                        max(mean1+sderr) +0.004,
                                        max(mean1+sderr) +0.004,
                                        mean1[2]+sderr[2]+0.001)))

p + geom_line(data = line_data,aes(x = x,y = y))
```

In general, you should avoid using things like `[` and `$` when you map aesthetics inside of `aes()`. The intended way to use **ggplot2** is usually to adjust your data into a format such that each column is exactly what you want plotted already.

You can't reference variables in `mytbl` in the `scale_*` functions because that data environment isn't passed along like it is with layers. The scales are treated separately than the data layers, and so the information about them is generally assumed to live somewhere separate from the data you are plotting.

Comment: thanks @joran, this is a solution, and I take the point of avoiding `[` and `$`. Just to clarify my understanding of function's behavior - `geom_line()` bluntly checks number of points passed and only allows to have the same number as length of `data` - is that correct?

Comment: @VasilyA Well, there's nothing special about `geom_line`. The non-standard evaluation is being handled the same way for all geoms. The key point is that if you specify a data frame at the `ggplot()` level, all subsequent action in `aes()` will be interpreted as taking place within the specific context of the data frame. And so it will expect things of that general shape/length.

Comment: I see, this check is on the level of `aes`, not `geom_line`. And I found that this check was introduced only since a certain release of `ggplot2` - that's why my code worked correctly before.